# Unable to figure out,No Build tools found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

Error:No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

Every time i used to gradle sync the project from android studio,I got above error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your gradle version in /projectName/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x;xxxx'
```

Then download the new version of the build tools 19.1 and change the following line in /projectName/moduleName/build.gradle

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.1" //Set this to 19.1 after SDK update
...
}
```

Sync your gradle files and it should be working now.